# I want to convert a bitmap image to byte array format in android. is it possible?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to convert and Image to Byte. The exact format that i want is shared below.

public static byte[] ImageByte = new byte[] { (byte)0x1b,(byte)0x42,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x33
                ,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x34,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x34,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x10,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x47
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x7e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7e,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31
                ,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcf,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31
                ,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xf0
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02
                ,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02
                ,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x3e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x03,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0c
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30
                ,(byte)0x0c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x0c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31
                ,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x1c
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x18,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x8e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x18,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x3c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7c
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31
                ,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31
                ,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x78,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32
                ,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x7c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x35,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x32,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x35,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68
                ,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x33,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x33,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2f,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x0a
                ,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2e,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x84,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x06
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x81,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x84,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x63,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf1,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc1,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x61,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x74,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x66,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x11,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9c
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x66,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x98,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x61,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x8c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x8c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x7f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x8c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x61,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf1
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c
                ,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x11,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdc
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x38,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc6
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x30,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x18,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xce,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x78,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x19,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x8e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xce,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x39,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x18,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x71,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf9
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x87,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xee,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf9,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1d,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xb8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c
                ,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdf,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x02,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc3,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdc,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1d,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc4,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x4e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x76,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf9
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc4,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcf,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x64,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x90,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x46,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xff,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x4e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7a,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcb,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xc6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9d,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xef,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x66,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xef,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3f,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xb0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xce,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x62,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x4a,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9d
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xc6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x05,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xcf,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x62,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x4e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x83,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x1d,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe6,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0x05,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x66,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x05,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcf,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x63
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcf,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfb,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdd,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xf5,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9d,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x6e
                ,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe7,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xfe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x0e,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdb,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x63,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xcb,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xf8,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe0,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x7b,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xdd,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x3c,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x9d,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xe6,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x64,(byte)0x01,(byte)0xed,(byte)0x01
                ,(byte)0xbe,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x2c,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00
                ,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x47,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x68,(byte)0x1b,(byte)0x45};

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing the format"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are taking from the image Via the Gallery intent. Open an input stream and then loop through it till you reach the End of the stream. In the loop read each byte and place in the array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[0];
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

InputStream inputStream =   getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
int len = 0;
while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
b = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [how to ask](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) on stack overflow. Now come to your question, try this code to get a byte array from bitmap,

```
Bitmap bitmap = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
```